# Storing Multiple Resolutions of Image Attachment in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

What is the best practice way of naming the database column of an image with multiple resolutions? Today I have both the original resolution and the encoded resolution of 480x480, but what if tomorrow I want to add 640x640 and also keep 480x480 and original? How would I name the columns in the db?

For example, I thought of this, but I'd rather get input first.

- `image_original`
- `image_480x480`
- `image_640x640`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know CarrierWave or refile Gems? This gem provide a good tools to store and manipulate images files. And you can easily upload you files to Amazon S3 with them

Comment: Yup! I use Paperclip. Editing the files is fine, but I'm not sure how to name the image in the database / S3.

Comment: Ok! I don't know how to do this using Paperclip. I've worked with paperclip some time ago and I can advice you that carrierwave is much better. Manipulate and send files with Fog to S3 is easy!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Paperclip, I suggest like below from [paperclip - github](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#quick-start)

```
# Rails 4
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```